# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut platform OTHER

Tags: android

How investigate about this error? I read this log from android market. Platform I see "OTHER".

```
Line 2637 and others:

    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
              public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(seek<10)
              {
              seek=10;
              seekBar1.setProgress(seek);
              }
    //        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(p), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              }
              public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              seek=progress;
              SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, 0);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
              editor.putInt("seek", seek);
              editor.putInt("progress", progress);
              editor.commit();
              textView1.setTextSize(seek);
              }
              });


    "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409f0460 self=0x12800
      | sysTid=12489 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1074803848
      | schedstat=( 1790000000 1790000000 3091 ) utm=159 stm=20 core=0
      at libcore.io.Posix.fsync(Native Method)
      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.fsync(BlockGuardOs.java:97)
      at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(FileDescriptor.java:71)
      at android.os.FileUtils.sync(FileUtils.java:111)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:577)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:491)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:512)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:434)
      at com.example.app.MainActivity$3.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:2637)
      at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:670)
      at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.trackTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:411)
      at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:349)
      at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5545)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5725)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2907)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2471)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:849)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:863)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2446)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Line 2637 from `MainActivity` is causing the issue. And apparently when the `onProgressChanged()` method of the `SeekBar` is invoked.

Comment: And why I see platform "other"? Which kind of platform is?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but an answer might still be useful.

There are two issues in the code above:

1. The call to `editor.commit();` commit() method is synchronous which means that every time it is called the data is written directly into the disc.
2. Calling `editor.commit();` inside `onProgressChanged()` method. Depending on the implementation this method might be called multiple times in a second. Combining it with the disk write operations on the UI thread it means that you are constantly writing and the UI is blocked.

**Possible solution:**

3. Save the required values("seek", "progress") into memory. save them into the shared prefs only when there is a risk that the data might be lost(Activity state change for example).
4. Replace `editor.commit();` with `editor.apply();`. Apply() methods is async so blocking the UI thread is much unlikely to happen.

You can see the full documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()